# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle11g

Below is my function in Oracle:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION CALCULATEINT
( DebtNo IN VARCHAR2
, JFlag IN VARCHAR2
, FloatingInterestRate IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER IS
AccInt NUMERIC(17,8):=0;
BEGIN
DECLARE 
      PrincipalDue NUMERIC(11,2);
      InterestDue NUMERIC(17,8); 

  IF (JFlag IN ('B', 'C', 'Y')) THEN
   BEGIN
        SELECT
            DEF_JUDG_PRINC_DUE ,
           DEF_JUDG_PRINC_RATE          
       bulk collect into PrincipalDue ,InterestDue 
        FROM
            DANT 
        WHERE
            AND DE_NO = DebtNo ;
      END;
  END IF;
  RETURN AccInt;
END;
```

I am getting errors below:

1.PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "IF" to continue.

2.PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: A function definition does not require the `declare` block. You can also not use `bulk collect` to store data in a scalar variable. You need to store the result of a `bulk collect` into a collection.

Comment: move the variable definitions between IS and BEGIN

Comment: I'm guess because of the bulk collect into scalars, like @a_horse_with_no_name said.  Also, you have to guarantee that only one row is found.   And noticed that you are not setting AccInt.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace
FUNCTION CALCULATEINT
( DebtNo IN VARCHAR2
, JFlag IN VARCHAR2
, FloatingInterestRate IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER IS
AccInt NUMERIC(17,8):=0;
BEGIN
DECLARE 
      PrincipalDue NUMERIC(11,2);
      InterestDue NUMERIC(17,8); 


   BEGIN
    IF (JFlag IN ('B', 'C', 'Y')) THEN
        SELECT
            DEF_JUDG_PRINC_DUE ,
           DEF_JUDG_PRINC_RATE          
       bulk collect into PrincipalDue ,InterestDue 
        FROM
            DANT 
        WHERE
            AND DE_NO = DebtNo ;

  END IF;
  END;
  RETURN AccInt;
END;
```

Move the if statement from before the anonymous begin to after the begin.
I am certain that is the error.
Correspondingly you also need to move the end statement after the end if block.
Hope this helps.